# Saving to json and redis from map

Tags: java, redis

I am trying to store some nested information in a redis server as well as a json at the same time.

I want the structure to look like this in redis, and then access the value(eid12345) as a key.

```
{
"mCat" : [eid1 : ["123", "234"], eid2 : ["1234", "234"], eid3 : ["2", "0", "1"]]
,
"fCat" : [eid1: ["986", "876"], eid3 : ["a", "hx"], eid31 : ["1"]]

}
```

The json obviously needs to have everything within double quotes.

```
{
"mCat" : ["eid1" : ["123", "234"], "eid2" : ["1234", "234"], "eid3" : ["2", "0", "1"]]
    ,
"fCat" : ["eid1": ["986", "876"], "eid3" : ["a", "hx"], "eid31" : ["1"]]

}
```

This is my code:

```
public static String getAllListsJSON() {
        String query = "MATCH (t:MALECAT) with t match (t)<-[r:CHILD_OF]-(subtag:MALECAT) WITH t,collect(subtag) as subtags return t.eid as eid, t.level as level,  REDUCE(relations = \"\", rel IN subtags| relations + \",\" + rel.eid) AS relations;";

        Iterable<Map<String, Object>> itr = Neo4j.queryLagData(query, null);

        ConcurrentHashMap<String, Object> mapOfMaleCatChildren = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Object>();

for (Map map : itr) {
            String tagID = (String) map.get("eid");
            String[] immediateChildren = ((String) map.get("relations")).split(",");
            List<String> listOfImmediateChildren = new ArrayList<>();
            for (String eachChildTagEID : immediateChildren) {
                if (!"".equals(eachChildTagEID)) {
                    listOfImmediateChildren.add(eachChildTagEID);
                }
            }
            Collections.sort(listOfImmediateChildren);
            mapOfMaleCatChildren.put(tagID, new JSONArray(listOfImmediateChildren));
        }
        RedisCacheManager.setWithInfiniteRedisTTL(maleCatListsKey, mapOfMaleCatChildren);
        return mapOfMaleCatChildren.toString();
    }
```

Please suggest how I can use the eids as a hash and also save the json in correct form at the same time.

Comment: My suggestion is to use Jackson objectmapper, create a pojo for your cats to be able to convert easily from json to object and vice-versa.

then for eids as hash, you could combine them then you could use SHA-1.

Comment: @AlexSales Thanks. I am already using a pojo for the cats. But I need to find a list of them from the neo4j query. Any pointers to how I can create a list of pojos from the neo4j?

Comment: @AlexSales Also, I didn't get why would I use SHA - 1

Comment: you could use any. :)